# Why are objective-c @interface definitions placed in a seperate .h file?

Tags: objective-c

I recognize that this is a general type of question but I'd be interested in your opinion on:

- why are @interface @protocol and @property definitons seperated into a .h header file and then imported into the implementation file?

Is there anybody out there who just defines everything in a .m file?

BTW> its not that I am planning on not using .h files, just trying to understand the thinking behind it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Objective-C relies on standard C infrastructure in which every compilation unit (`.m`) is compiled separately and then all of them are linked together.

This means that the static type checking phase of the Objective-C compiler will need just the `.h` files to know the characteristics of declared classes (eg. signatures of methods) but just to ensure that everything is used as it is supposed to be, and this is why you `#import` them in other source files that require what you declared inside the header.

if you have `A.h/.m` and `B.h/.m` which uses A you can think of the header file like a contract: "if you want to use A, I will link its binary code at the end of the compilation phase, what A is able to provide is described in this header file and this is the only thing you should know"

Comment: Thanks @Jack, this is helping me understand the compile process. In theory, could the compiler extract the @interface definitions out from a file that was #import'ed?

Comment: BTW> its not that I am planning on not using .h files, just trying to understand the thinking behind it

Comment: If you mean a `.m` then theoretically it could, but the `#import` (and in general `#include`) directive are managed by the preprocessor that literally replaces that directive with the content of the file specified, it doesn't do any kind of dirty work for you. This is why you need to split them. You can consider them as forward declarations: since your `.m` file uses something that is not directly declared there but that at the same time is compiled in another unit you need to explain to your code the characteristics of the class that is implemented somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks again @Jack for your detailed explanation! Appreciate it.